# Maximum amount of services and receivers allowed on Android

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver

My app have 6 services (3 IntentService) and 4 receivers (1 is local).
I was wondering:

1. Is there any restrictions for registering services and receivers (like max amount)?
2. In my specific case, is it healthy to have so many services/receivers? Would it get killed by Android during runtime?

Comment: dozen or so is ok imho

Comment: Is there any documentation backing that or is it based on your own experience?

Comment: i know it will sound unproffesional, but its my intuition...:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any restrictions for registering services and receivers (like max amount)?

I'd guess there's an upper bound of two billion or so (`Integer.MAX_VALUE`).

That being said, I'd consider your number of services to be a code smell.

> Would it get killed by Android during runtime?

I am not aware of Android taking the *number* of services (let alone receivers) into account in terms of its prioritization scheme for terminating processes.

Comment: In that case, what would be the max recommended amount of services?

Comment: @AlonLevanon: IMHO, a maximum of two should suffice. One `IntentService` that handles all your transactional work, and perhaps an additional `Service` for durable operations under user control (e.g., media playback). Bear in mind that you can use `Intent` extras to signal different things for the service to do via `startService()` and `onStartCommand()`, if you are using the command pattern. So, for example, there's little value in three `IntentServices`, when you can have one with an `if` statement in `onStartCommand()` to distinguish three (or more) distinct commands.

Comment: @AlonLevanon: Occasionally apps may have need for more, if they require some specialty service classes (e.g., `AccessibilityService`), but that's rare, and the odds of them needing one of those *and* an `IntentService` *and* a regular `Service` are fairly small.

Comment: My app should handle tons of pushes of three kinds: location updates, data changes on server and data changes on other users.
I've created an IntentService for handling each type, in order to avoid too much load on one IntentService and to make sure I'll get everything.
location updates pushes can get to couple of hundreads in one minute.
In my case, should I merge all of my IntentServices into one?

Comment: @AlonLevanon: If your concern is load, the answer isn't "create a bunch of services" but instead "create a better service". Adding more services doesn't somehow cause a phone to sprout a better CPU, every `startService()` call involves an IPC, etc. For example, you could roll your own `IntentService`-workalike that uses a `ThreadPoolExecutor`, to allow you to process more than one command at a time, yet still tune the number of threads. Or, skip the command protocol and use an in-process event bus to deliver work to a `Service` for processing on a thread pool.